# Script optimization C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization

I'm working on an autosplitter for a program called Livesplit.
It's used for speedrunning and by creating autosplitter you can watch memory addresses to tell the app to do an action when the value changes.

It is using C# so it shouldn't be a problem to do some magic.

I'm a complete coding noob with pretty much zero programming experience.
I have no idea how to optimize this code, so it first does not look bad and second so the app itself doesn't have problems with it.

Right now, my code looks like this but it is horrifying.

```
state("GoingDown", "v1")
{
    int Loading : "GoingDown.exe", 0x6874EC;
    string30 LevelFirst : "GoingDown.exe", 0x263E28;
    string30 LevelSecond : "GoingDown.exe", 0x263E37;
    string15 Cutscene : "GoingDown.exe", 0x26B543;
}

state("GoingDown", "v2")
{
    int Loading : "GoingDown.exe", 0x6874EC;
    string30 LevelFirst : "GoingDown.exe", 0x263E40;
    string30 LevelSecond : "GoingDown.exe", 0x263E4F;
    string15 Cutscene : "GoingDown.exe", 0x26B55B;
}

init
{
    if (modules.First().ModuleMemorySize == 0x79A726)
        version = "v1";
    else if (modules.First().ModuleMemorySize == 0x79B000)
        version = "v2";
}

start
{
    //return (old.Level == "M00_CIV_Intro_1" && current.Level == "M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1" && current.Loading != 0);
    return (current.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1") && current.Loading != 0 && old.Loading == 0 || current.LevelSecond.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1") && current.Loading != 0 && old.Loading == 00);
}

split
{
    if (old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelSecond.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M02_HOO_Subway_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M02_HOO_Subway_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M02_HOO_Subway_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M02_HOO_Subway_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M02_HOO_Subway_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M02_HOO_Subway_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M02_HOO_Subway_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M02_HOO_Subway_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m02_hoo_subway_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m02_hoo_subway_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m02_hoo_subway_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m02_hoo_subway_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m02_hoo_subway_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m02_hoo_subway_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m02_hoo_subway_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m02_hoo_subway_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_4", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    //if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    //  return true; (CUTSCENE NO NEED TO SPLIT)

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M04_HOO_Subway_layup_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M04_HOO_Subway_layup_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M05_HOO_Battle_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M05_HOO_Battle_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M05_HOO_Battle_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M05_HOO_Battle_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M05_HOO_Battle_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M05_HOO_Battle_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M05_HOO_Battle_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M05_HOO_Battle_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    //if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M06_IND_Bulletproof_0") && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M06_IND_Bulletproof_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M06_IND_Bulletproof_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M06_IND_Bulletproof_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    //  return true; (CUTSCENE NO NEED TO SPLIT)

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m06_ind_bulletproof_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m06_ind_bulletproof_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m06_ind_bulletproof_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m06_ind_bulletproof_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m06_ind_bulletproof_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m06_ind_bulletproof_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m06_ind_bulletproof_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m06_ind_bulletproof_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M06_IND_Bulletproof_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M06_IND_Bulletproof_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M06_IND_Bulletproof_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M06_IND_Bulletproof_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    //if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_0") && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    //  return true; (CUTSCENE NO NEED TO SPLIT)

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    //if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m08_hoo_remember_alamo_0") && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m08_hoo_remember_alamo_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m08_hoo_remember_alamo_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m08_hoo_remember_alamo_0", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    //  return true; (CUTSCENE NO NEED TO SPLIT)

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m08_hoo_remember_alamo_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m08_hoo_remember_alamo_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m08_hoo_remember_alamo_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m08_hoo_remember_alamo_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m08_hoo_remember_alamo_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m08_hoo_remember_alamo_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m08_hoo_remember_alamo_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m08_hoo_remember_alamo_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M08_HOO_Remember_Alamo_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M08_HOO_Remember_Alamo_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M08_HOO_Remember_Alamo_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M08_HOO_Remember_Alamo_3", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1a", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m09_civ_cat_and_mouse_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m09_civ_cat_and_mouse_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m09_civ_cat_and_mouse_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m09_civ_cat_and_mouse_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m10_civ_bridge_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m10_civ_bridge_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m10_civ_bridge_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m10_civ_bridge_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("m10_civ_bridge_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m10_civ_bridge_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("m10_civ_bridge_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":m10_civ_bridge_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M11_CIV_Blimp_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M11_CIV_Blimp_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M11_CIV_Blimp_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M11_CIV_Blimp_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        return true;

    // NOT SURE IF IT WORKS
    //if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M11_CIV_Blimp_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M11_CIV_Blimp_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    //  return true; 

    // Final split
    if (current.Cutscene.Contains("M11_010") && current.Cutscene != old.Cutscene)
        return true;
}

isLoading
{
    return (current.Loading == 0);
}
```

I don't know how to deal with so many if statements. Put it in a dictionary perhaps? But then I have no idea how to make that.

Comment: What is your problem? Your code quality?

Comment: Yes, is there anyway to optimize it?

Comment: Can Split even return false? Also can't you test whether old.LevelSecond.Equals(":" + current.LevelSecond) ?

It's really horryfing what is this eve supposed to do?

Comment: yes it can. I don¨t think that's possible?
and like I said, it basically watches the levelname address and when it changes from "level" to ":level" it considers it a passed mission and splits.

Comment: So what are you actual trying to do? Try to describe your problem in like you would to a layman.

Comment: This is not a question related to c# to be honest more an ASL script question.

Comment: @Radle I was always bad at explaining.

You load up a game you go into menu, Levelfirst now is "menu". You choose a level, it changes to "m001....", if you leave the level it goes back to menu and of course the value goes with it. If you finish the level, suddenly this address does not work and moves to LevelSecond where it stays for the rest of the game until the game crashes. If the game crashes and you were in the middle of a game, let's say "m005..." I have to compare again, LevelFirst until I finish the level and it moves on to LevelSecond....

Comment: @FilipCordas Well, fair but it's basically c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could tell you could cut a lot of code by doing something like

```
 Func<string,string,bool>  eq = (a,b) => a.Equals(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    var levels = new string[] 
    {
       "M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1",
       "M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1a",
       "M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_2",
       "M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_3",
       "M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_4",
       "M02_HOO_Subway_1a",
       "M02_HOO_Subway_1b",
       "m02_hoo_subway_2",
       "m02_hoo_subway_3",
       "m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_1",
       "m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_2",
       "m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_3",
       "m03_hoo_whos_got_beef_4",
       "M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1a",
       "M04_HOO_Subway_layup_1b",
       "M04_HOO_Subway_layup_2",
       "M05_HOO_Battle_1",
       "M05_HOO_Battle_3",
       "m06_ind_bulletproof_1",
       "m06_ind_bulletproof_2",
       "M06_IND_Bulletproof_3",
       "M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_1",
       "M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_2",
       "M07_HOO_Blind_Justice_3",
       "m08_hoo_remember_alamo_1",
       "m08_hoo_remember_alamo_2",
       "M08_HOO_Remember_Alamo_3",
       "M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1a",
       "M09_CIV_Cat_and_Mouse_1b",
       "m09_civ_cat_and_mouse_2",
       "m10_civ_bridge_1",
       "m10_civ_bridge_2",
       "M11_CIV_Blimp_1"
    };

    if(levels.Any((level) => eq(old.LevelFirst,level) &&  eq(current.LevelSecond, ":" + level) || eq(old.LevelSecond,level) && eq(current.LevelFirst, ":" + level)))
       return true;

    // NOT SURE IF IT WORKS
    //if (old.LevelSecond.Equals("M11_CIV_Blimp_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M11_CIV_Blimp_2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || old.LevelFirst.Equals("M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && current.LevelSecond.Equals(":M01_HOO_Tranes_Hood_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    //  return true; 

    // Final split
    if (current.Cutscene.Contains("M11_010") && current.Cutscene != old.Cutscene)
        return true;
```

But is this really more readable I don't know.

Comment: This looks astonishingly more awesome, problem is I get a compilation error:

at if(levels.Any......) line at the bottom with unexpected $ symbol cs 1056

Comment: A ok this is c# version probably not supported I will make an edit

Comment: A thousand thanks to you kind sir, it totally works!

Could you disect it a little bit? I want to understand it, and I'm not sure if I do one hundred percent.

Comment: For `Any()` read up on [`Linq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx); It basically enumerates through the array (`levels`) and returns true on the first occurance of the condition inside the brackets being true.  The item being enumerated is passed into the brackets via as `level` variable (`(level) => `)

Comment: @ChrisWalsh Also the ()=> syntax is called [lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions). they are weary common in C#. In fact they are used so much that I completely forgot that someone new might not know what they do.

Comment: @FilipCordas, ah yes, forgot to mention that.  I use them all the time too.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing `old.LevelFirst` and `old.LevelSecond` against lots of static values and doing a case insensitive comparison.  Why not, at the top of your `split` method, take local lowercase copies of these values:

```
var first = old.LevelFirst.Lower();
var second = old.LevelSecond.Lower();
```

This makes comparisons easier as follows:

```
if(first == "..." || first == "..." || first == "..." || ...)
    return true;
```

Next, I think you have a bug.  You have if statements that say:

```
if(first == "xxxx" && second == "yyyy" || second == "zzz")
    return true;
```

This statement will return true if `second == "zzz"` regardless of that value of `first` as `||` has a lower precedence than `&&`.  You need to put brackets around your `second` comparisons i.e.

```
if(first == "xxxx" && (second == "yyyy" || second == "zzz"))
    return true;
```

Next, look at using a `switch` statement for first level instead of `if` statements (ensuring the values you compare with are lower case:

```
switch(first)
{
    case "m01_hoo_tranes_hood_1" :
        return 
            (second == ":m01_hoo_tranes_hood_1") ||
            (second == "m01_hoo_tranes_hood_1") ||
            (second == ":m01_hoo_tranes_hood_1");

    case "m01_hoo_tranes_hood_1" :
       .....
}
```

These is a logic change here - I am assuming that if `first` is `m01_hoo_tranes_hood_1` but not any of the `second` values, then the logic will fall right through to the end and return false.  Your `if` logic could allow for the same `first` value to match later on and have different logic but this can be incorporated into the above case statement anyway.

Finally, look at the variable values.  Are the colon `:` prefixes relevant or is it a case that "they may or may not be there so I need to check for both"? If so, back on those two `var first = / var = second =` statements, and remove the `:` prefix which should reduce the comparisons:

```
if(first.StartsWith(":"))
    first = first.Substring(1); // Remove first character
```

Now you don't need to include the colon prefix in all your compares.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris, noted.
As for the switch. I'm not sure if that can work?

Let's say I fist load the game, I'm in the menu - current LevelFirst holds "menu", I go to a level, old is "menu" curret is "m001....". If I leave the leavel, it switches around (current "menu"; old "m001...."). Now if I go to a level and finish it, suddenly current LevelFirst holds random giberish and all of it moves to LevelSecond, so current holds ":m001...." and old is empty. However let's say I'm in the middle of a game and the game crashes, now the game is back to using LevelFirst and repeats the same thing.

Comment: I have to assume the game crashes at any point, hence why so many if statements.

Comment: I think it would help if you clarified what `old.LevelFirst`, `old.LevelSecond`, `current.LevelFirst` ,`current.LevelSecond` actually are.
I'm guessing `old` is the previous state and `current` is the new state that you are just entering?  What about `LevelFirst` vs `LevelSecond`? (is it these four variables in total?)